# UIScrollView not scrolling when included into viewcontroller embedded into a navigation controller

Tags: objective-c

I have made a view controller embedded in a navigation controller.  In the view controller, I have inserted a scroll view that contains some buttons and text fields.  In the `viewDidLoad` method, I have inserted the following code to initialize the `scrollView`:

```
[scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake:(1000, 1000)];
```

But the view does not scroll.  I have tried the same scenario but without embedding the view controller into a navigation controller and it was working.  Does anyone know the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this in `viewDidAppear`. The UI components willnot get set completely in `viewDidLoad`

Try,

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake:(1000, 1000)];
}
```

Should work .

Comment: Good, then you can mark this answer as accepted, just check the tick mark to the left side. Thanks